# Inequality for Gamma function

Tags: proof-writing, special-functions

Prove that $$0<\frac{\Gamma(x+y)}{\Gamma(xy)-1}\leq3$$ for all $x>0,y>0, xy>2.$ And equality holds $x=y=2.$

Comment: +1 The graph of this is insanely beautiful.

Comment: no it is unbounded, take $x$ very large and $xy = 2 +\epsilon$

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, if x = y = 2, then doesn't the expression become (2 + 2 - 1)!/(2*2 - 1)! = 3!/3! = 1?

Answer (score 3):

Both claims are wrong: 
For $x=y=2$
$$\frac{\Gamma(x+y)}{\Gamma(xy)-1}=\frac{6}{6-1}=\frac{6}{5}$$
For $x=y=1.5$
$$\frac{\Gamma(x+y)}{\Gamma(xy)-1}\approx 15.0372439$$